# Trouble Drawing Nested Circles

Tags: java, graphics, geometry, nested, awt

My program asks the user how much circles they want drawn and is supposed to draw an N amount of nested circles based on the user input.  My code so far is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class DrawCircles extends JFrame {

DrawCircles(){
    add(new Circle());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the number of circles you wish to display");
    int circles = Integer.parseInt(number);
    DrawCircles d = new DrawCircles();
    d.setTitle("Nested Circles");
    d.setSize(500, 500);
    d.setVisible(true);
    d.setLocation(200,200);

}//end main method




}//end class

class Circle extends JPanel{
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawOval(135, 125, 200, 200);
}//end paint()
}//end class
```

I have no idea how to take the user input from the main method and use it in a for loop to draw an N amount of circles.  Also, I have to adjust my JFrame size accordingly to the amount of circles I will have to fit all of them in it and I don't know how to do that either.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by not overriding `paint`, but instead use `paintComponent`, and make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent` when you do. Take a look at [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

Simply pass the `circles` value as a parameter to the constructor of the `Circle` class and/or provided a setter to change the value